# Comparing two files and printing lesser of two based on a key

Tags: shell, awk

Content of first file:

```
$cat File1
KEY1,4999
KEY2,3999
KEY3,5999
KEY4,10999
```

Content of second file:

```
$cat File2
KEY1,11905
KEY2,6872
KEY3,2393
KEY4,296360
```

Expected output file:

```
 KEY1,4999
 KEY2,3999
 KEY3,2393
 KEY4,10999
```

Searching for a one liner command to get the expected output. Requirement here is to print lesser number for each key, by comparing two files.

Comment: What efforts did you make? Can you post it even if its not solving your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Awk`** is "your friend" in this case:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
     NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next }
     $1 in a{ 
         print $1, ($2 < a[$1]? $2 : a[$1]) 
     }' file1 file2
```

The output:

```
KEY1,4999
KEY2,3999
KEY3,2393
KEY4,10999
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` can be your friend

```
$ cat f1
KEY1,4999
KEY2,3999
KEY3,5999
KEY4,10999
$ cat f2
KEY1,11905
KEY2,6872
KEY3,2393
KEY4,296360
$ awk -v FS="," '{$0=($2<$4)?$1 "," $2:$3 "," $4}1' <(paste -d',' f1 f2)
KEY1,4999
KEY2,3999
KEY3,2393
KEY4,10999
```